# RedisConnectionException: Unable to init enough connections amount

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, redisson

Today I start the spring boot project in MacBook Pro with M1 pro(with 8 performance core and 2 efficient core), shows error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'redissonClient' defined in class path resource [misc/redisson/RedissonConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.redisson.api.RedissonClient]: Factory method 'redissonClient' threw exception; nested exception is org.redisson.client.RedisConnectionException: Unable to init enough connections amount! Only 10 of 24 were initialized. Redis server: cruise-redis-master.reddwarf-cache.svc.cluster.local/10.108.202.100:6379
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:486) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
```

the remote redis was a single redis master server with 2 slaves. my redission config look like this:

```
package misc.redisson;


import org.redisson.Redisson;
import org.redisson.api.RedissonClient;
import org.redisson.config.Config;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

/**
 * @author dolphin
 * @version 1.0
 * @date: 2020/9/5 9:50 
 */
@Configuration
public class RedissonConfig {

    @Value(value = "${spring.redis.host}")
    private String redisHost;
    @Value(value = "${spring.redis.port:6379}")
    private Integer redisPort;
    @Value(value = "${spring.redis.timeout:2000}")
    private Integer redisTimeOut;
    @Value(value = "${spring.redis.password}")
    private String redisPwd;


    @Bean(name = "redissonClient")
    public RedissonClient redissonClient() {
        Config config = new Config();
        config.useSingleServer()
                .setAddress("redis://" + redisHost + ":" + redisPort)
                .setPassword(redisPwd)
                .setTimeout(redisTimeOut)
                .setDatabase(1);
        RedissonClient redissonClient = Redisson.create(config);
        return redissonClient;
    }
}
```

and the redis server(2Core and 8GB memory in the cloud) max client config:

```
connected_clients
120
cluster_connections
0
maxclients
10000
```

the remote server was a single kubernetes node, and connected local machine and remote server by telepresence. why did this happen? what should I do to fixed this problem?